# YOY growth based on ID

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to calculate year or year growth for a variable in a Pandas dataframe. My data looks like this:

| Year | Country | Industry | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | USA | Manufacturing | 5 |
| 2000 | Mexico | Manufacturing | 10 |
| 2001 | Mexico | Manufacturing | 15 |
| 2002 | Mexico | Other | 20 |

I have different number of observations depending on the Country or Industry. Expected output:

| Year | Country | Industry | Value | YOY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | USA | Manufacturing | 5 | NaN |
| 2000 | Mexico | Manufacturing | 10 | NaN |
| 2001 | Mexico | Manufacturing | 15 | 50% |
| 2002 | Mexico | Other | 20 | NaN |

I tried different things including:

```
df.groupby(['Country','Industry','Year'])['Value'].pct_change()

df['YOY'] = (df['Value'] - df.sort_values(by=['Country','Industry','Year']).groupby(['Country','Industry'])['Value'].shift(1))) / df['Value']
```

The first line calculates growth between rows without resetting for a new Country or Industry. The second one has incoherent results.

Any lead I could take? Thanks!!

Comment: What should it be if there's missing  year for a country and industry ?

Comment: There are no missing years within the data, a series (Mexico, Other for example) could start later but once it starts, there are no missing data. If I have 1999,2001,2022 data,  both 1999 and 2001 should be NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['YOY'] = df.groupby(['Country','Industry'])['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Year Country       Industry  Value   YOY
0  2000     USA  Manufacturing      5   NaN
1  2000  Mexico  Manufacturing     10   NaN
2  2001  Mexico  Manufacturing     15  50.0
3  2002  Mexico          Other     20   NaN
```